# Ignore instance of recursive function Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I haven't found anything near a solution yet, if you could at least give me a clue..
I have this function:

```
def analizar_consulta(consulta, v):
    print('\ntomar consulta: {}\n'.format(consulta))
    #transformar todas las variables en su contenido
    consulta = transformar_variable(consulta, v)
    if consulta[0] in diccionario_funciones.keys():
        parametros = list(filter(lambda x: not(isinstance(x,list)), consulta[1:]))
        consultas = list(filter( lambda x: isinstance(x,list) , consulta[1:]))
        print('parametros: {}'.format(parametros))
        print('consultas: {}\n'.format(consultas))
        if len(consultas) > 0:
            pasadas = list(map(lambda x: analizar_consulta(x, v), consultas))
            parametros.append(pasadas)
        else:
            return diccionario_funciones[consulta[0]](*parametros)
        return diccionario_funciones[consulta[0]](*parametros)
    else:
        raise Exception('Comando no encontrado')
```

as it is recursive, sometimes it takes arguments from inside the first parameter as a new parameter for itself in a new instance, but sometimes the first argument of the new parameters is a list, which raise an error on the line 5 (`consulta[0]`)
Is there a way to, if there is a list (which only contain numbers), it just returns it instead of continuing with the rest of the code?
Sorry for the code is in Spanish, if you don't understand something I can edit it.

when I try it whit `["comparar", ["PROM", "x"], ">", ["DESV", "y"]]` this parameter, it raises the error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Instead of saying "which raise an error on the line 5" you should say what error it raises. Ideally post the complete error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes. Add at line 4.5:

```
c0 = consulta[0]
if isinstance(c0, list) and all(isinstance(i, int) for i in c0):
    return
```

That having been said, the fact that you don't know what your parameter list contains indicates that there's a design problem in your code. You just called a function to do some kind of transformation on your list:

```
consulta = transformar_variable(consulta, v)
```

Why didn't you fix it?

Consider taking a look at the overall code, and asking a *different* question on SO: "How can I do (whatever it is)?"